# Chrome Doesn't Accept jQuery Symbol ($)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Not a problem as such but during development I noticed that Chrome doesn't accept the '$' symbol often used instead of 'jQuery'. But runs fine when 'jQuery' is used.

Noticed this with using Chromes developer tools and thought it was odd, anyone any ideas why?

Comment: did you try to check what `$` is in the console?

Comment: There may be any other library or something which uses $ notation. Maybe prototype or something...

Comment: works for me :D try `console.log($)` what returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not problem with chrome. It's due to jquery conflict. `$.noConflict()` fixes this.

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict()` if `$` is the problem ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me:

[image]

Make sure you have **no other** framework (that uses `$`) loaded on the page.

Comment: @DanielA.White looks like one to me.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a shorthand for `jquery`. Now, if some other libraries also uses `$` along with `jQuery`, there occurs collisions in the usage of `$`.

It can be resolved by the following the below:

```
<script src="mylibrary.js" ></script> 
<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict(); 
</script>
```

Now after the first library `jQuery` takes full control over `$`, then the `jQuery.noConflict()` freesup the usage of `$`.
But now in your custom js whenever you want to make use of a jQuery method you can't use `jQuery`, you must use `$`.